# UPDATE Inner Join with limit?

Tags: mysql

I wanted to update up to 8000 rows with `INNER JOIN`.

I get an error:

> Incorrect usage of UPDATE and LIMIT

It does work if I don't include the `INNER JOIN`

```
UPDATE `loop`
INNER JOIN data ON data.number = loop.number
SET robot = 1
WHERE `done` != 1 AND `robot` = 0
limit 8000
```

How do I get this to work? Example SQL would be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080403/update-with-order-by-and-limit-not-working-in-mysql. Apparently limit can only be used with SELECT statements

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: @CircularReference Limit can be used with update statements

Answer (score 0):

I assume your table has a primary key which I will call number here. Then copy the first 8000 numbers in a temporary table and join your update to that table:

```
create temporary table if not exists PKs (number integer);
insert into PKs select number from loop where done != 1 and robot = 0 limit 8000;
update data inner join PKs on data.number = PKs.number set data.robot = 1;
drop table PKs;
```

Maybe my usage of the done and robot field is not correct, but from your statement it's not clear to which table they belong.