# How to don't lock whole table?

Tags: mysql

I have two table `dsl_checkins` and `area_distance`.
In `area_distance` 3 rows :

```
distance
area1
area2
```

Example:

```
distance = 3456
area1 = phoenix
area2 = houston
```

So i need get from  dsl_checkins table entry where distance is lowest and need carry about `usage_flag` field. My idea was use following query:

```
UPDATE dsl_checkins DC
    join area_distance AD
    on AD.area2 = DC.area
set DC.usage_flag=1,
    DC.id = (SELECT @dsl_id := DC.id)
WHERE DC.active = 1 AND
      DC.offline = 0 AND
      usage_flag = 0 AND
      AD.area1 = 'houston'
ORDER BY AD.distance ASC, RAND()
limit 1;
```

but i get error:

> Error Code: 1221. Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY

Any idea how to do it without lock whole dsl_checkins table?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080403/update-with-order-by-and-limit-not-working-in-mysql ... you can use a subquery instead.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you, but i don't understand how i can use it in my case

Answer (score 0):

`Order by` is not compatible with `Update`

[UPDATE with ORDER BY and LIMIT not working in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080403/update-with-order-by-and-limit-not-working-in-mysql)