# Insert record and increment values of other records

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have a table with a custom sort order column.

```
ID    NAME    ORDER
1     Jack    4
2     Jill    2
3     Mike    5
4     Mark    1
5     Bill    3
```

I would like to insert a new record with an ID of 6, a NAME of Jane, and an ORDER of 3. I would like to insert it such that the old records are incremented to make room for the new record, resulting in something like this:

```
ID    NAME    ORDER
1     Jack    5
2     Jill    2
3     Mike    6
4     Mark    1
5     Bill    4
6     Jane    3
```

Can this be done using a SQL script? I was looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9080506/330663), but I'm not sure it can be made to work in my case. Plus it requires an extra table to temporarily hold values, which I would like to avoid.

Thanks.

[edit]

I forgot to add that there is a unique constraint non the third column. Though I understand there are ways of getting around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with two queries:

```
update mytable set order = order + 1 where order >= 3;
insert into mytable(id, name, order) values(6, 'Jane', 3);
```

Note, however, that this create a race condition, and might not behave properly under concurency stress.

A better solution would be not to store the customer ordering, but compute it on the fly in your queries (you can create a view to make it easier). For this, you would need to describe the logic behind the ordering.

Comment: Yeah, I would normally use a script to calculate the ordering inside or outside of MySQL. But the ordering in this case is mostly arbitrary with no pattern.

Comment: When I run your script I get error 1062 and complaints about duplicate values. I have tried disabling unique checks using `SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;` but without success. Not sure what else to try.

Comment: Is there some way to set the `order` in reverse? I.e. larger numbers first, then smaller numbers?

Comment: I simply needed to tack on `ORDER BY order DESC` to the end of your update statement. Now it works, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO mytable(id, name, order) values (6, 'Jane', 0);
UPDATE mytable SET order = CASE WHEN id % 2 <> 0 THEN order + 1 ELSE order / 2;
```